# c++: How do I store and read an unordered_map in a memory mapped file

Tags: c++, unordered-map, memory-mapped-files, solaris-10, g++4.9

I would like to store and later read an `unordered_map` in a memory-mapped file using `C++` on `Solaris` (compiler `g++ 4.9.2`). I have quite a large data that needs to be stored as a key-value pair. But, maintaining an `unordered_map` in memory takes up lot of memory at the same time key-value pair provides me access in O(1) time for the underlying data How can I use a memory mapped file using `mmap` to store and read data?

Comment: _"How can I use a memory mapped file using `mmap` to store and read data?"_ Hmm, maybe using a custom allocator (placement `new`) for `unordered_map`? Pointers may become a problem though.

Comment: Yes to get both side of the world and save memory but get O(1) access too

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/libs/interprocess) provides "offset_ptr" and related allocators for doing this sort of thing. I have not used it myself, though.